# Using couchbase as a single node

Tags: couchbase

Can couchbase  be used as only one node for development purposes, or benchmarking inserts, updates and reads? 
And can couchbase run in a computer with 1vCPU and 512 MB of RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/pre-install.html) covers the minimum recommended specification for running Couchbase Server.

> The minimum hardware specifications to install and effectively operate
>   Couchbase Server are:
>
> Dual-core x86 CPU running at 2GHz. 4GB RAM (physical).

It then goes on to say...

> The specification can be as low as 1GB of free RAM beyond operating
>   system requirements and a single CPU core.